# flutter swiper package avoid to swipe to next position, it stay on first

Tags: flutter

I have a working code before null safety flutter upgrade. But after the migration, the same code doesn't work.

I had a simple horizontal swipe card, but now something force the swipe to stay on the first position or rebuild. When I remove `didChangeDependencies` (function I use to load when data change) the swipe is OK. I think when data is load by `didChangeDependencies`it refresh `new Swiper.children(` and force to return always to first index position.

But I can't do without `didChangeDependencies`, how can I do ?

Here is the package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper_null_safety/example
Here is my code:

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

final MyInheritedWidgetState state = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
}
```

---

```
                                                      new Swiper.children(

                                                      viewportFraction: 0.8,
                                                      scale: 0.6,
                                                      autoplay: false,
                                                      loop: false,
                                                      control: new SwiperControl(

                                                        size: 25.0,
                                                        color:  Color(0xffff9a7b),

                                                        disableColor: Colors.transparent ,
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all (5.0),
                                                      ),

                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                      Card1()
                                                      Card2()
                                                      Card3()
                                                      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would need to have a controller or index saved in the state that could hold the state of the downstream widget so on rebuilds the state stayed the same.

After looking at this package it doesn't appear you can pass in an Index or Controller to the widget so it will be rebuilt any time something above it on the stack is rebuilt.

Is it possible to reorganize your page so that the swiper is not under it in the stack?

Comment: thank you, for the reply, all my swiper children's display a counter, so each seconds the data change I can't move this function :(

Comment: Do you only have a few children? If so you can use the itemBuilder of the swiper package and just rebuild inside the itembuilder. It's a little dirty, and would mean opening more streams, but it might be a quick and dirty way of making it work if you're in a pinch. Otherwise you could fork the package and add the state/controller, or reach out to the package author with a feature request.

Comment: I have 4 children. I'm a noob I never use itembuilder, I will try to use other package, or I don't know

Comment: perhaps create a pageview

Comment: itemBuilder is just the swiper items, you can create a new widget and pass that in, or as suggested a pageview would work just fine.  The pageview would have a controller that would have state held in the top level widget, so it would be immune to the rebuilds from the updated counter. If you share more code - how your counter works, then it would be easy to show you how.

Comment: have I no problem with pageview :)